# To find the most frequently used value in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_Account
(
   ID Int IDENTITY(1,1),
   AccountNo Varchar(500)
)
```

.......................................

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Account
SELECT 'AE000111'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000112'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000113'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000114'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000115'
```

........................................

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Temp_AccountProc
(
   @AccountNo    Varchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT ID
   FROM   Temp_Account
   WHERE  AccountNo     =      @AccountNo

  END


   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111'

   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000112'

   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000113'

   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111'

   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111'

   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000112'
```

I want to know the most frequently used value in the table. Is there any DMV or any method to find the given output ?

```
 ------------------------------------
    AccountNo          UsedCount
  ------------------------------------

      AE000111            3

      AE000112            2

      AE000113            1
```

---

Answer (score 0):

1. add a new column to your table or create another temp table with columns as UsedCount and AccountNo,
2. in your procedure, when ever an account no is selected select the used count column value for that account number too
3. increment the used count
4. execute an update statement to update the used count for that AccountNo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add [UsedCount] column
2. When call procedure set [UsedCount] + 1

---

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_Account
(
   ID Int IDENTITY(1,1),
   AccountNo Varchar(500),
   [UsedCount]  int
)
INSERT INTO Temp_Account
SELECT 'AE000111',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000112',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000113',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000114',0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AE000115',0
;

CREATE PROCEDURE Temp_AccountProc
(
   @AccountNo    Varchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT ID
   FROM   Temp_Account
   WHERE  AccountNo     =      @AccountNo

   update Temp_Account
   set [UsedCount] = [UsedCount] +1
   WHERE  AccountNo     =      @AccountNo

END
```

---

```
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111';
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000112';
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000113';
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111';
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000111';
   EXEC Temp_AccountProc 'AE000112';

   select * from Temp_Account
   where [UsedCount] > 0;
```

---

**Result:**

```
| ID | AccountNo | UsedCount|
|----|-----------|-------------|
|  1 |  AE000111 |           3 |
|  2 |  AE000112 |           2 |
|  3 |  AE000113 |           1 |
```

---

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/655aa/1/5)

Comment: This is just an example and we are using more than 40 procs for this table. It is not possible to update as u mentioned in all procs.Is there any method using DMV or any other methods?